# How can I set 30 Business Days from current date not 30 calendar days?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to replace 30 calendar days with 30 Business days in which weekends are excluded. How I can do that?

```
maxDate:new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()+30))
```

I tried some calculation figuring out total weeks and than subtract the weekends from that, but it is not happening.